# Join R tibbles with values taken with different time-steps

Tags: r, join, dplyr, tibble, data-wrangling

I'm trying to join two tibbles which contain values taken with different time steps.
For example:

```
data_fine <- tibble(t_fine = seq(50,51, length.out = 25),value_fine = seq(1,25))
head(data_fine)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  t_fine value_fine
   <dbl>      <int>
1   50            1
2   50.0          2
3   50.1          3
4   50.1          4
5   50.2          5
6   50.2          6

data_coarse <- tibble(t_coarse = seq(50,51, length.out = 10),value_coarse = seq(1,10))
head(data_coarse)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  t_coarse value_coarse
     <dbl>        <int>
1     50              1
2     50.1            2
3     50.2            3
4     50.3            4
5     50.4            5
6     50.6            6
```

I'd like to add a column in `data_fine` with the `values_coarse` taken in the same period (assigning the value taken at the closest previous or next `t_coarse`). For example, if I assign the `data_fine` to the ones with the previous `t_coarse`, I'd like to get something like `data_tot`:

```
head(data_tot)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  t_fine value_fine values_coarse
   <dbl>      <int>         <dbl>
1   50            1             1
2   50.0          2             1
3   50.1          3             2
4   50.1          4             2
5   50.2          5             3
```

I'd like this to work even if the times are not equally spread as in this example.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tricky part that might be unexpected is that your t_fine values are actually "50.00000" "50.04167" "50.08333" "50.12500" "50.16667" etc. and your t_coarse values are "50.00000" "50.11111" "50.22222" "50.33333" "50.44444" etc. because you are requesting 25 or 10 spots across a range, inclusive of the endpoints. So you're comparing 24ths to 9ths, and don't don't line up exactly in most cases, even if the first decimal digit is matching.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_segment(data = data_fine, color = "gray70",
               aes(x = t_fine, xend = t_fine, y = 0, yend = value_fine)) +
  geom_segment(data = data_coarse, 
               aes(x = t_coarse, xend = t_coarse, y = 0, yend = value_coarse))
```

[image]

If your data is small, one brute force way to line these up for the closest match would be to calculate all the pairwise time distances and select the best for each. If your data is more than, say, 10k rows, I expect this would start to get too inefficient, and it would become much faster to use a non-equi join in `data.table`.

```
library(tidyverse)
crossing(data_fine, data_coarse) %>%   # from tidyr, incl in tidyverse
  mutate(t_diff = abs(t_coarse - t_fine)) %>%
  group_by(t_fine) %>%
  slice_min(t_diff) %>%
  ungroup()


## A tibble: 26 x 5
#   t_fine value_fine t_coarse value_coarse t_diff
#    <dbl>      <int>    <dbl>        <int>  <dbl>
# 1   50            1     50              1 0     
# 2   50.0          2     50              1 0.0417
# 3   50.1          3     50.1            2 0.0278
# 4   50.1          4     50.1            2 0.0139
# 5   50.2          5     50.1            2 0.0556
# 6   50.2          6     50.2            3 0.0139
# 7   50.2          7     50.2            3 0.0278
# 8   50.3          8     50.3            4 0.0417
# 9   50.3          9     50.3            4 0     
#10   50.4         10     50.3            4 0.0417
## … with 16 more rows
```

Here's a figure to check the result visually:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_segment(data = data_fine, color = "gray70",
               aes(x = t_fine, xend = t_fine, y = 0, yend = value_fine)) +
  geom_segment(data = data_tot, color = "red", # This is output of prior chunk 
               aes(x = t_fine, xend = t_coarse, y = 0, yend = value_coarse)) +
  geom_segment(data = data_coarse, 
               aes(x = t_coarse, xend = t_coarse, y = 0, yend = value_coarse))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot! By adding another condition in your script I managed to get not just a match with the closest time (regardless if past or future), but to specify if the "direction" of the match. The changed code is this one: `mutate(t_diff = abs(t_coarse - t_fine),s = sign(t_coarse - t_fine)) %>% filter(s==+1)`. By specifying `+1` or `-1` one can change the direction of the match